# Using pgfkeys to make a custom tikzpicture command with multiple use of addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, pgfkeys

Consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% DATA 1
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.txt}
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
\end{filecontents*}

% DATA 2
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.txt}
1 15
2 10
3 7
4 5
5 2
6 1
\end{filecontents*}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393622/using-key-values-in-newdocumentcommand
\pgfkeys{/myplot/.is family, /myplot,
    filename/.initial=data.txt,
    linecolor/.initial=black,
}
\newcommand\myplotvals[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/myplot/#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand\myplot{m} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfqkeys{/myplot}{#1}% keep key changes local
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot [\myplotvals{linecolor},mark=none] table {\myplotvals{filename}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\myplot{filename=data1.txt,linecolor=red}

\end{document}
```

Using `pgfkeys` I've created a command called `\myplot` which takes data from a .txt as an input and you can optionally set the line color.

This works well for 1 data set. My question is, does anyone know how I could adapt this method to allow adding multiple data sets.

In my MWE, I've included a second data set called `data2.txt`. What I want the command to do is essentially generate something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [red,mark=none] table {data1.txt};
\addplot [blue,mark=none] table {data2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Basically, it would be great if I could specify a second .txt file (or potentially `n` text files) and it would automatically add more `\addplot` commands as required. Is this even possible to do? I don't know what the input would have to look like, maybe something like `\myplot{filename={data1.txt,data2.txt},linecolor={red,blue}}` ? But perhaps that doesn't work?

**Update**

Just to be clear, although in my MWE the file names are sequential, in my real example the file names do not iterate numerically. Therefore I have to specify each file name individually.

Comment: `pgfplots` already has `cycle lists` to deal with the color list so all you need is to rewrite the command in such a way that it loops over file names, which is straightforward.